# Shutdown not running in cron

Tags: python, bash, macos, cron

I have a part of my script to automatically shutdown my Mac.

```
...  
print("Shutting down now")
time.sleep(3)       
shutdown_now = "echo {} | sudo -S /sbin/shutdown -h now".format(shutdown_info["password"])
subprocess.Popen(shutdown_now, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print("THIS SHOULD NOT DISPLAY")
```

The script is run in cron. When I receive the cron mail.

```
...  
Shutting down now
THIS SHOULD NOT DISPLAY  
?  
At EOF
```

The script executes and finishes without even shutting down my Mac. Am I missing something to be added to my script?

Comment: The user running the script is a valid `sudoer` right?

Comment: What is the content of `shell.stdout.read()`, when `shell=subprocess.Popen(shutdown_now, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: @Kingsley, yes the user is a `sudoer`

Comment: I used you code `shell=subprocess.Popen(shutdown_now, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` and  `print(shell.stdout.read())`. It worked! How is that?

Comment: Uh, good question.  Does your script `wait()` sometime later? Maybe the  parent process exited, terminating the child subprocess before the subprocess got to do anything ?

Comment: it doesn't `wait()`. Shutting down is the end of the script flow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use cron to specify the execution of the command, not a script. This just simplifies the troubleshooting.

1. sudo crontab -e
2. 59 23 * * * root /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now

MM HH DD 00 WW Command

MM: minute
HH: hour
DD: day of the month
OO: month
WW: day of week
Command with full path

So above: as root, execute /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now every day of the week, every month at 11:59 PM.